# How do I stop Webstart from locking up?

Tags: java, swing, deployment, java-web-start

We have converted [one of our projects](http://quantumleapbuzz.com/) to java webstart recently and are having various problems with it.  We previously were using an installer and the app runs really well with the installer.  The app does a lot of fetching web pages off of the internet in order to analyze them.  Sometimes when running the app we get the below popup. Even worse, when this happens, the user interface locks up and the only way to recover is to bring up the task manager and kill the app.  This only happens some times and appears to be somewhat random.

[image]

I thought it might be due to the problem [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050202/why-is-java-7-requesting-network-permissions-for-a-signed-application), but it still happens when we upgrade to the very latest version of Java.  Is there anyway to fix this?  Is an applet a better way to go or will that cause the same problems?  I like the idea of Webstart because it provides automatic updates.

Here is the jnlp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- JNLP File for Quantum Leap Buzz-->
<jnlp spec="1.6+" codebase="http://pbafiles.quantumleapinnovations.com/Buzz/Webstart" href="QuantumLeapBuzz.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Quantum Leap Buzz</title>
        <vendor>Quantum Leap Innovations</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://www.quantumleapbuzz.com"/>
        <description kind="one-line">Quantum Leap Buzz</description>
        <description kind="short">Quantum Leap Buzz</description>
        <icon href="http://pbafiles.quantumleapinnovations.com/Buzz/Webstart/Logo_32x32.jpg" />
        <icon kind="splash" href="splash2copyright.png" />
        <offline-allowed/>
        <shortcut online="true">
            <desktop/>
            <menu submenu="Quantum Leap Innovations">
                <menu submenu="Quantum Leap Buzz"/>
            </menu>

        </shortcut>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6.0+"  initial-heap-size="256m" max-heap-size="900m"/>
        <jar href="jars/activation-1.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/bcprovs-131.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/c3p0-0.9.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/commons-codec-1.5.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/commons-collections-3.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/commons-digester-1.6.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/commons-io-1.3.2.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/commons-lang-2.4.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/commons-math-2.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/commons-pool-1.5.6.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/commons-validator-1.3.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/fest-assert-1.2.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/fest-reflect-1.2.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/fest-swing-1.2.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/fest-swing-junit-1.2.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/fest-util-1.1.2.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/geonames-1.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/hibernate-c3p0-3.5.6-Final.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/itext-2.1.7.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jackson-core-asl-1.7.3.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jackson-jaxrs-1.5.5.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.3.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jackson-xc-1.5.5.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jasperreports-4.1.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jaxb-api-2.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jcommon-1.0.12.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jdom-1.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jersey-client-1.6.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jersey-core-1.9.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jersey-json-1.4.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jersey-multipart-1.6.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jettison-1.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jfreechart-1.0.9.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jgeocoder-0.4.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jide-common-3.3.8.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jsoup-1.6.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/jta-1.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/junit-4.8.1.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/leapworks-core-3.2.48.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/leapworks-util-3.2.48.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/log4j-1.2.16.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/lucene-analyzers-3.3.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/lucene-core-3.3.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/machine_learning_data_utilities-3.2.48.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/mimepull-1.4.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/oauth-client-1.8-ea04.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/oauth-signature-1.8-ea04.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/poi-ooxml-3.8-beta2.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/prefuse-beta-20071021.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/qlbuzz-2.0.19.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/restfb-1.6.9.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/statistics_utilities-3.2.48.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/stax-api-1.0-2.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/swingx-core-1.6.2-2.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/swingx-ws-1.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/timingframework-1.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/trove-2.1.0.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/twitter-text-1.4.3.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/twitter4j-core-2.2.6.jar"/>
        <jar href="jars/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar"/>
    </resources>
     <application-desc main-class="us.quantumleap.galaxy.social.ui.AdvancedAppFrame"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: That's weird... Did you sign the application with a valid certificate and put the all-permissions tag in the JNLP file?

Comment: All jar files are signed and we added the all permission tag.  I added a link to the web page where you can find the jnlp file.

Comment: Try searching the bug DB/ raising a bug.  But be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) first.

Comment: Could you say more about why could it not be bug_id=7177349?  You wrote "it still happens when we upgrade to the very latest version of Java" – do you mean Java 1.7.0u5?  If so, bug_id=7177349 is still open as far as I can tell.

Comment: @unhillbilly I thought it might be bug: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7177094 which is supposedly fixed as of Java 1.7u3.  Yes, the bug still happens in Java 1.7u5.  You are right, it might be bug_id=7177349.  That is frustrating that it is not fixed yet.

Comment: JaNeLA raised some issues that we will look into.  Thanks @Andrew Thompson

Comment: @AndrewThompson Wow! JaNeLA is very thorough. Nice tool.

Comment: Thanks.  After a cache flush and fresh launch, is the problem fixed?

Comment: The cache flush does seem to make it behave a little better, but the problem invariably seems to happen again.  We are now looking at solutions other than Webstart (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254328/java-web-start-alternative).

Comment: How about java 32 bit version?  did you try that?

Comment: I don't recall which versions we tried.  However, the version of Java on the client machine is mostly out of our control.  We can make recommendations, but that is about it.  We switched over to using Getdown and it seems to work better.